# Zend_Db_Expr() doesn't execute as intended in a View in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, view, zend-db

I just want to do this simple task with Zend Framework:

```
<input type="hidden" name="modification_date" value="<?php echo new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()');?>" />
```

As you can see I'm trying to instantiate Zend_Db_Expr to be able to insert a date in an input with `NOW()` in a View, however this is not working, because what I've got is this `value="NOW"` instead of something like this `value="2012-10-04 12:14:56"`

Seems quite simple. I had this working before but U had to uninstall and reinstall MySQL for another reason and now it doesn't work.

I've also tried `new Zend_Db_Expr('SELECT NOW();')` because in my MySQL if I execute NOW this way I got the date.

Comment: If you want this done in Mysql you don't need any code in your application. Just set a column on your table to TIMESTAMP with a default value of Current http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 2):

`Zend_Db_Expr` doesn't return value of your statement. It returns specific predefined string for query. Why you can not use `Zend_Date`?

```
<input type="hidden" name="modification_date" value="<?php echo Zend_Date::now();?>" />
```